# ios - force wait Alamofire response before returning in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

I have a situation where I had to check the provided mobile number on both signup and login through an OTP code. I had everything setup in my `Accounts` calss to reuse them on the `SignUpViewController` and `SignInViewController`.

In the `ViewControllers` I want to send OTP first, then check if it is sent from the server response to push the `VerificationViewController`, I'm using `Alamofire` for networking and `SwiftyJSON` for parsing JSON responses. Now let's dig deep to the core of my problem:

Here is a part of my `SignUpViewController` class

```
var acc: Accounts = Accounts()

@IBAction func signupAction(_ sender: Any) {
        if validateFields() {
            let fname = self.firstName.text!
            let lname = self.lastName.text!
            let pnum = self.phoneNumber.text!
            self.acc.setFirstName(fn: fname)
            self.acc.setLastName(ln: lname)
            self.acc.setPhoneNumber(pn: pnum)
            let result = self.acc.sendOTP()
            if (result) {
                let targetVC = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "signupVerfication") as? SignupVerficationViewController
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(targetVC!, animated: true)
            }
            else {
                CustomComponents().alertWithTitle(title: "Error", message: "Unable to Verify Phone Number,Please Try again!", ViewController: self)
            }
        }
}
```

And here is a part of my `Accounts` class

```
func sendOTP() -> Bool {
        let conf = APIConfig()
        var returnedResult = false
        conf.setURL(url: "patient/auth/send-totp")
        conf.setHeader(head: ["Content-Type": "Application/json"])
        conf.setBody(body: ["phone_number": self.phoneNumber])
        print(self.phoneNumber)
        Alamofire.request(conf.getURL(), method: .post, parameters: conf.getBody(), encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: conf.getHeader()).validate(statusCode: 200..<600).responseData { response in
            let status = response.response?.statusCode
            print(status!)
            let swiftJSONVar = JSON(response.result.value!)
            print(swiftJSONVar)
            if (status == 200) {
                returnedResult = true
            }
        }
        return returnedResult
    }
```

I always get the alert as an output whenever I run the app, despite the fact that as you can see I debugged the response by printing it here `print(status!)` and here `print(swiftJSONVar)`. The output of the print is `200` as status code and I got the rest of my response.

I had been looking into many Tutorial online like: [Grand Central Dispatch Tutorial for Swift 4](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5370-grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-for-swift-4-part-1-2) and [Secure Coding With Concurrency in Swift 4](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/secure-coding-in-swift-4-with-concurrency--cms-29917) and more but couldn't implement the GCD on my code blocks.

I need your help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sendOTP method has return type `Bool` which returns immediately as `Alamofire` request is `asynchronous` and you are setting value of returnedResult false at top which returns immadiately without waiting for response. After the response comes from the Alamofire the returnedResult is set to true but there is no way to inform caller. As false is returned from sendOTP method it is showing error alert.

Use closure instead of returning bool from sendOTP, which takes Bool and returns void

```
func sendOTP(_ completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    let conf = APIConfig()
    var returnedResult = false
    conf.setURL(url: "patient/auth/send-totp")
    conf.setHeader(head: ["Content-Type": "Application/json"])
    conf.setBody(body: ["phone_number": self.phoneNumber])
    print(self.phoneNumber)
    Alamofire.request(conf.getURL(), method: .post, parameters: conf.getBody(), encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: conf.getHeader()).validate(statusCode: 200..<600).responseData { response in
        let status = response.response?.statusCode
        print(status!)
        let swiftJSONVar = JSON(response.result.value!)
        print(swiftJSONVar)
        if (status == 200) {
            completion(true)
        } else {
            completion(false)
        }
    }
}
```

now you can call like

```
self.acc.sendOTP { (result) in
    if result {
        //show vc
        let targetVC = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "signupVerfication") as? SignupVerficationViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(targetVC!, animated: true)
    } else {
        //show error alert
        CustomComponents().alertWithTitle(title: "Error", message: "Unable to Verify Phone Number,Please Try again!", ViewController: self)
    }
}
```

Along with [GCD](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5370-grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-for-swift-4-part-1-2) tutorial, I would recommend [URLSession](https://www.raywenderlich.com/567-urlsession-tutorial-getting-started) and [Alamofire](https://www.raywenderlich.com/35-alamofire-tutorial-getting-started) tutorials as well to understand how Networking works in iOS.